# video_player: how to suppress TCP output

Tags: flutter

After I initialize a new VideoPlayerController, I get output similar to this in the console:

```
[43.1 9320C4C3-349A-420C-B60D-4074259E7BF1 10.0.0.7.63778<->52.72.148.144:80]
Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Duration: 30.601s, DNS @0.000s took 0.041s, TCP @0.042s took 0.001s
bytes in/out: 638/386, packets in/out: 1/1, rtt: 0.066s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
```

These lines print out a few times after initializing the controller and during playback of a network video.

My code (below) is directly from the example code on [this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player) page.

Is this expected? Can I suppress this output?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new VideoPlayerController.network(
      'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4',
    )
      ..addListener(() {
        final bool isPlaying = _controller.value.isPlaying;
        if (isPlaying != _isPlaying) {
          setState(() {
            _isPlaying = isPlaying;
          });
        }
      })
      ..initialize(); // <-- This is the line that first prints the output
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1280 / 720,
            child: new VideoPlayer(_controller),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? _controller.pause : _controller.play,
        child: new Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just seems to be TCP debug information for your own reference, so you can verify the actual network side of the VideoPlayer is functional (it's a semi-buggy plugin - for instance, I've had trouble with WEBMs on Android).  If you were shipping a release build and wanted to make sure you weren't doing unnecessary logging, you could alter the plugin source directly.